# window.open doesn't open a fresh window every time

Tags: javascript

When I run window.open, it opens up and whatever the contents were before appear while it loads the new contents. So in my system, you can click purchase item, and it directs you to a payment provider, and then when you're done (or any time during the process) you close the window via the X in the corner.

When you go to pay for another item, the window opens again and it remembers the previous contents, while it loads. This is ugly and confusing for people that are seeing details briefly about the previous order.

Any idea how to wipe the contents or stop it remembering?

`window.open(d.url, 'mywindow', '');`

I tried clearing with:

`mywindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = '';`

but it says mywindow does not exist. Also I don't know if this would interrupt the loading of the actual url.

Any ideas?

Edit: I should add, it opens a page on the same domain and then that page redirects to the 3rd party.

Comment: [You cannot fiddle with `mywindow.document` if it's a different domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: since you are using the window instance name 'mywindow' in all your requests it will be be opening in the same window, if you want to differentiate the windows, then change the instance name.

Comment: So I should just randomise the window name every time? It's strange how it remembers even when X is pressed to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you should be given new window name.

```
window.open(d.url, 'mywindow' + Math.random(), '');
```

Like:

```
window.open("https://www.google.co.in/", 'mywindow2' + Math.random())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the window a new name.

```
window.open(d.url, 'newNameOnEveryWindowOpen', '');
```